# Detect the target parent element when perform mouse "onwheel Event"

Tags: javascript, html, mousewheel

What this code should do is:

I have a list of element IDs, each of these target elements contains other elements. When I use the mouse wheel and the cursor is on one of the target elements (or some of its child element) some action must be performed.

I wrote this code and it works fine. What worries me is that each time the code has to perform many calculations to complete the task. If anyone has an idea how I can optimize this task I will be happy to share. Тhanks in advance.

*Please, Run code snippet on Full page*

```js
var flag = true;
var myTarget;
var myRes;
var myI;

// The IDs of the target elements
var array = ['elOne', 'elTwo', 'elThree'];
var newArray = array.reverse();

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var myEl = document.getElementById(array[i]);
    myEl.parentElement.addEventListener("wheel", event => {
        mouseWeel(event.target);
    });
}

function mouseWeel(cmp) {
    if (cmp !== myTarget) {
        for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            var res = cmp.closest('#' + newArray[i]);
            if (res) { break; }
        }

        myTarget = cmp;
        myRes = res;
        myI = i;
    }

    cmd = myTarget; res = myRes; i = myI;

    if (flag) {
        var myEl = document.getElementById(newArray[i]);
        myEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
        flag = false;
    } else {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="elOne" style="width:100%; height:90vh; background:orangered;">
    <div id="elTwo" style="width:50%; height:45%; background:orange; margin: auto;">
        <div style="width:80%; height:50%; background:orange; padding: 10px;">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="elThree" style="width:50%; height:45%; background:blue; margin: auto;">
        <div style="width:80%; height:50%; background:blue; padding: 10px;">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</span>
            <div
                style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin-left: -200px; background:blue; padding: 20px; transform: rotate(-45deg); opacity: 0.5; color: white;">
                I am a child of the blue element
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at a throttle or debounce of some sort.

https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-patterns/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your idea is not bad! But there are some situations with a slight overlap of elements or z-index change of position... where it will return an incorrect result. And to avoid this it will be necessary to make many more calculations than those that the code is currently doing.

Comment: First you wrote "What worries me is that each time the code has to perform many operations to complete the task." Now you're saying "[...] it will be necessary to make many more calculations than those that the code is currently doing." Which is it?

Comment: I made a change in the example of my OP to illustrate which part I don't know how to do if I use the method you propose. Please look the child of the blue element.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea how to optimize one of the processes! Thank you!